# Sigmoid functions for a biased random number generator

Tags: random-variables, curves, inverse-function

I'm trying to create a random number generator biased toward certain values. To do this I'm using a random number [0,1] as the parameter for a sigmoid curve. I've found the perfect curve to get the results I want,

$c\left( \frac{1}{1+exp(-ax + b(a-16) + 8))}\right) + (1-c)x$,

where $a = [16,\infty)$ is the tightness of the bias, $b = [0,1]$ is the position of the bias and $c = [0,1]$ is the strength of the bias.

However, I need this as a function of y, as it biases away from the number if I plug in an x value at the moment. [Here's an example of how I want to find a random number.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKXae.png)

I've tried to inverse this function and have got stuck. When $c=1$, it's a lot simpler and I've got the function,

$-c\frac{ln|x^{-1} - 1|+b(16-a)-8}{a}$.

However, when $c\neq1$, I cannot find the inverse, and simply adding $(1-c)x$ as before doesn't work due to the asymptotes at $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Am I missing something obvious or is there a better way to do what I want? I wan't this to be as computationally simple as possible! [You can play around with the curves in desmos here.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ausri4l6je)

Comment: Why not use simpler functions? Piecewise linear or quadratic, for instance. Or, rather than inversing a function with a locally larger derivative, apply a function with a locally smaller derivative ($x\to x^3$) is a trivial example, you could find a more suitable polynomial, or another combination of function - a spline maybe). It will be easier to help if you explain what you want to do with these random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the function $\frac{1}{a^{|x-m|}}$ where $m$ is the value I'm biased toward and $a = 1 + \frac{b^2}{n}$ where n is the interval of x, and b is the strength of the bias. Using integration, I picked a random area between the min and max $x$ values and solved for $x$.

Comment: This is a very effective way to create biased random numbers or otherwise shape an arbitrary number into a biased curve.